# How to set a variable in the caller scope, like the extract() function

Tags: php, extract, inject

I know that directly setting a variable in the scope of caller is probably not a good idea.
However, the PHP `extract()` function does exactly that! I would like to write my own version of `extract()` but cannot figure out how to actually go about setting the variables in the caller. Any ideas?
The closest I have come is modifying the caller's `args` using `debug_backtrace()`, but this is not exactly the same thing...

Comment: You're trying to break basic rules of the language.  Don't.  Your colleagues will thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could explain why you want to do that and we might come up with a better approach?

Comment: I use `extract()` when passing function arguments as an array, but I want a way of calling my own function and immediately supplying the default values for unspecified arguments; ie replace this argument checking with a single call:
`function myfunc($args) { extract($args); if (!$number) $number = 10; if (!$name) $name = "john"; etc... }`
I suppose the next best thing is first filling in the default values with a pass-by-ref function, and then calling `extract()` on that:
`$defaults = array('number'=>15,'name'=>'mike'); clean_args(&$args, $defaults); extract($args);`

Comment: PS sorry for the inline code, it won't let me multi-line it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't modify local variables in a parent scope - the method which extract() uses is not exposed by PHP.

Also, what you get back from debug_stacktrace() isn't magically linked to the real stack. You can't modify it and hope your modifications are live!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

You could only do it in a PHP extension. If you call an internal PHP function, it will not run in a new PHP scope (i.e., no new symbol table will be created). Therefore, you can modify the "parent scope" by changing the global `EG(active_symbol_table)`.

Basically, the core of the function would do something like `extract` does, the core of which is:

```
if (!EG(active_symbol_table)) {
    zend_rebuild_symbol_table(TSRMLS_C);
}
//loop through the given array
ZEND_SET_SYMBOL_WITH_LENGTH(EG(active_symbol_table),
    Z_STRVAL(final_name), Z_STRLEN(final_name) + 1, data, 1, 0);
```

There are, however, a few nuances. See the [implementation of `extract`](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/branches/PHP_5_3/ext/standard/array.c?revision=300371&view=markup#l1313), but keep in mind a function that did what you wanted wouldn't need to be as complex; most of the code in `extract` is there to deal with the several options it accepts.

Answer (score 1):

You can abuse the $GLOBALS scope to read and write variables from the caller of your function. See below sample function, which reads and write variables from the caller scope.

And yes, I know its dirty to abuse the $GLOBAL scope, but hey, we're here to fix problems ain't we? :)

```
function set_first_name($firstname) {
    /* check if $firstname is defined in caller */
    if(array_key_exists('firstname', $GLOBALS)) {
        $firstname_was = $GLOBALS['firstname'];
    } else {
        $firstname_was = 'undefined';
    }   

    /* set $firstname in caller */
    $GLOBALS['firstname'] = $firstname;

    /* show onscreen confirmation for debugging */
    echo '<br>firstname was ' . $firstname_was . ' and now is: ' . $firstname;
}  

set_first_name('John');

set_first_name('Michael');
```

The function returns the following output:

```
    <br>firstname was undefined and now is: John
    <br>firstname was John and now is: Michael
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how badly you need to do this.  If it's only for source beauty, find another way.  If, for some reason, you **really** need to mess with parent scope, there's always a way.

#### SOLUTION 1

The safest method would be to actually *use extract itself* for this job, since it knows the trick. Say you want to make a function that extracts elements of an array but with all the names backwards - pretty weird! -, let's do this with a simple array-to-array transformation:

```
function backwardNames($x) {
    $out = [];
    foreach($x as $key=>$val) {
        $rev = strrev($key);
        $out[$rev] = $val;
    }
    return $out;
}

extract(backwardNames($myArray));
```

No magic here.

#### SOLUTION 2

If you need more than what *extract* does, use *eval* and *var_export*.  YES I KNOW I KNOW everybody calm down please.  No, eval is not evil.  Eval is a power tool and it can be dangerous if you use it without care - so use it with care. (There is *no way to go wrong* if you only eval something that's been generated by var_export - it doesn't give any way to intrusions even if you put values in your array from an untrusted source.  Array elements behave well.)

```
function makeMyVariables() {
    $vars = [
        "a" => 4,
        "b" => 5,
    ];
    $out = var_export($vars,1);
    $out = "extract(".$out.");";
    return $out;
}

eval(makeMyVariables());   // this is how you call it
// now $a is 4, $b is 5
```

This is almost the same, except that you can do a lot more in eval.  And it's significantly slower, of course.

However, indeed, **there is no way to do it with a single call.**